# How to use the "E" and "Z" keys in unreal engine?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So the keyboard keys work for me in unreal: awsd

But the e and z keys don't work for panning the camera

Are these keys still available for use in unreal? Or could it be something in the setup?

My engine is running 4.17.2 
I am using the first person shooter blueprint using c++ code.
I made no modifications to the blueprint and just hit "play" to test the blueprint out

Comment: at the moment I also tested with using the "launch" instead of "play", with similar result though mouse movements are more flexible it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to go into 'Project Settings' under the 'Edit' menu and then check under 'Input' to make sure that E and Z are active bindings.  If not you can create new axis bindings for them, i.e. 'Pan' where E corresponds to a positive axis value, and Z corresponds to a negative axis value, or vice-versa.